# Visual Studio (15). Как в конструкторе найти элемент, зная его название?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Просто работаю с проектом, который не я создавал, есть там на форме `TabControl`, **15 вкладок**, в каждой по дюжине кнопок. И почти все называются а-ля `"button20"`.

В коде нахожу по ключевому слову обработчик нажатия нужной кнопки, как теперь на форме её отыскать, только глазками?

Comment: Какой тип формы? Их несколько. WPF, cshtml, aspx?

Comment: Тип формы-старая добрая WinForm c#